# template plugin?

Tags: plugin

do you have any simple and working template plugin to use for programming ?
I have tried [this](https://github.com/drbeco/vimtemplates) but to be honest I didn't understand how to use it. I have found [this](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/) but I didn't understand how to install it.

Thank you, I gave up to install a plugin for template because it's too complicated.

Comment: Questions asking for plugin recommendations are off-topic as they tend to generate opinion-based answers. You might be able to rephrase your question as “How do I do X?” to which “try plugin Y” may be an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In mu-template case, that I'm maintaining, you'll have to register at least 4 plugins in your plugin manager -- yeah, I know, 4 seems a lot, but [I don't like duplicating my code, and I'm dreaming of a day when people will use plugin managers that handle dependencies...](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/design_notes.md#regarding-dependencies)

```
The main, required, plugins:
'LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib'
'LucHermitte/lh-style'
'LucHermitte/lh-brackets'
'LucHermitte/mu-template'

The optional one to have a multi-cursors like feature
'tomtom/stakeholders_vim'

Another optional one used in a few default snippets
'LucHermitte/lh-dev'

And I have even more snippets in lh-cpp for C++ and C
'LucHermitte/lh-cpp'
```

Then you also need to be aware of the [old, and non-usual, approach](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/blob/master/doc/workflows.md#the-placeholders) taken in mu-template regarding placeholders as it could be really confusing.

Comment: @Luc-hermite I don't use plugin manager because they often give problems, also they're not available as package but I have to install it manually. Also in your documentation you take it for granted many things that are not granted. For example I know what is vam but you didn't say where to put that lines. I don't know what is vim-flavor and I don't want make a recursive research for 2 hours just to install a plugin for templates. I have tried to install vundle and with it others plugin but it give me around 15 errors.

Comment: What I mean to take for granted is that the person that install my plugins has already installed other plugins, and is familiar to what he/she does usually. Either manually (in which case I list the repositories of all the dependencies), or through a plugin manager, and given the list of dependencies I provide I expect my end-user to know how to register that list. For the special case of VAM or vim-flavour users, installing my plugin will be easier.

Comment: With VAM, once it's up and running, it could be as simple as `:InstallAddons mu-template@lh` once, and `:ActivateInstalledAddon mu-template@lh` in the `.vimrc` after activating VAM itself, or on demand. But it could be also [much more complex](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/vimrc_core.vim#L931) when we want to support proxies.

Comment: Anyway, just use the method you're used to with the list of plugins I provide.

Answer (score 1):

You might like [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips).

It's a bit complex (but you could say most snippet plug-ins are), but you can find [screen casts](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips#screencasts) covering UltiSnips to help you get started with it.

You'll probably want to use the snippets from [honza/vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets) together with UltiSnips (in fact, the UltiSnips quick start instructions mention them specifically.) They should cover a lot of the common ground, for most programming languages, and get you started quickly.